# Flutter - AVD in Android Studio terminates: WARNING | Failed to process .ini file...android\avd\Pixel_XL_API_28.avd\quickbootChoice.ini for reading

Tags: android, flutter, android-emulator, android-virtual-device

When trying to run an ***Android Virtual Device (AVD)*** in ***Flutter*** using ***Android Studio*** this warning pops up and the AVD immediately terminates.

```
WARNING | Failed to process .ini file C:\Users\WIN10\.android\avd\Pixel_XL_API_28.avd\quickbootChoice.ini for reading.
```

And this is what idea.log prints  (\Users...\AppData\Local\Google\AndroidStudio2022.2\log\idea.log)

```
2023-05-19 20:32:27,145 [ 626746]   INFO - #i.f.r.d.DeviceDaemon - starting Flutter device daemon #3: D:/Flutter/SDK/flutter/bin/flutter.bat daemon
2023-05-19 20:32:28,179 [ 627780]   INFO - #i.f.r.d.DeviceDaemon - flutter device daemon #3: Flutter assets will be downloaded from https://storage.flutter-io.cn. Make sure you trust this source!
2023-05-19 20:32:28,179 [ 627780]   INFO - #i.f.r.d.DeviceDaemon - flutter device daemon #3: Starting device daemon...
2023-05-19 20:32:32,018 [ 631619]   INFO - #c.a.t.i.d.DeviceManagerAndroidDebugBridge - []
2023-05-19 20:32:32,055 [ 631656]   WARN - #c.a.t.i.a.AvdManagerConnection - Unable to determine if Pixel_XL_API_28 is online, assuming it's not
```

Flutter doctor runs with no warnings. I was able to previously use AVDs, so not sure why it suddenly doesn't work.

I have tried wiping the AVD; using other Android emulators; and reinstalling the the AVD & flutter SDK - but keep running into this error. Please help!

Answer (score 0):

The question is a bit older but for those who may have a similar problem, here is my solution:

I recently had the same problem after a Windows update. In my case it was because Windows Security prevented Android Studio from creating the necessary *.ini files to start the emulators after the update. So you could disable the Windows security completely or add an **"exception"** for the path of Android Studio where the emulators are located in the Windows security settings. In my case this was **C:\Users\username\.android**.

Hope the answer helps :)